# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2n}\right)\ldots\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}n}\right)$

Tags: calculus

Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2n}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{4n}\right)\ldots\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}n}\right)$.

(This is not my homework. One of my friends gave this to me.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apply the GM-AM inquality to get:

$$\begin{align}
\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1+\frac1{2^{j-1}n}\right)&\leq\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\frac{1+\cdots+2^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}}\right)^n\\
&\leq\left(1+\frac2{n^2}\right)^n
\end{align}$$

Since last expression tends to $1$, the limit is $\leq1$

Since each factor is greater than $1$, the limit must be $1$.

Comment: what's a DM inequality?

Comment: Sorry for the typos ant mistakes. I think that now it is correct.

Comment: How do you apply the AM-GM inequality ? I suppose you use $(x_1x_2\ldots x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq \frac{x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n}{n}$ for some $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$. Can you tell me which formula you use for $x_i$ ?

Comment: $x_j=1+\frac1{2^{j-1}n}$

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you only show the upper bound here. You also need to show the lower bound to establish the limit of the original sequence.

Comment: @Alex: "Since each factor is greater than 1, the limit must be 1."

Answer (score 5):

Let $y$ be the value of limit. Then,
$$\ln y=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{k-1}n}\right)$$
Since the denominator in $\dfrac{1}{2^{k-1}n}$ is very large, we can work under the approximation $$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{k-1}n}\right) \approx \frac{1}{2^{k-1}n}$$
Hence,
$$\ln y=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^{k-1}n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow y=e^0=\boxed{1}$$

Comment: I don't find that not bounded approximations and "large numbers" can be in a proof.

Comment: @ajotatxe: I myself think that the solution is incorrect. It looks as if I posted a similar answer to Mehdi stating it in a different way.

Comment: If you put $\leq$ instead of $\approx$ you get an upper bound for the limit, and the lower bound is easy.

Comment: @ajotatxe: I am sorry if I am being dumb but is the lower bound zero?

Comment: Yes, the point is that upper and lower bound are the same, so you can say what exactly the limit is.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it $1$? The fractional expressions inside the parentheses are zero as $n\to \infty$.

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$$
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2n}=0$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}n}=0$$

Consequently the answer is $1$

Comment: Take for example:
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac1n)^n=e$

Comment: You have to be careful, because the number of factors doubles when you increase $n$ by $1$. So even though the factors reduce in size it is not so immediate that this is the dominant feature of the product.